# LNK2005 Already Defined error when linking my library

Tags: c++

I've made a library when i try and use it in another project i get a LNK2005 error.

Structs.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace Structs
{
    struct GameObject
    {
        std::string name;

        struct PosPoints
        {
            double px;
            double py;
        };

        std::vector<PosPoints> Points;

        double centroid[2];
        bool active;
        bool init;
    };
    std::vector<GameObject> objects;
}

#endif
```

Structs.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Structs.h"

struct Structs::GameObject gameObject;
std::vector<Structs::GameObject> objects;
```

CoreFuncs.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CoreFuncs.h"
#include "Structs.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//render
extern struct Structs::GameObject gameObject;
void RenderShapes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Structs::objects.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Structs::objects[i].Points.size()-1; j++)
        {
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex3f(Structs::objects[i].Points[j].px, Structs::objects[i].Points[j].py, 0);
            glVertex3f(Structs::objects[i].Points[j + 1].px, Structs::objects[i].Points[j + 1].py, 0);

            glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1, 0);
            glVertex3f(0.9, 0.9, 0);

            glEnd();
        }
    }   
}
```

[image]

The issue stops happening when i comment out the `#include "Structs.h"` in `CoreFuncs.cpp` So I assume that inlcude is what is causing the issues. I have looked around and found many sources using `extern` but i cant seem to get it working here.

Comment: Inside `namespace Structs` you have `std::vector<GameObject> objects;`. It is a definition, not a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Your header file is declaring an actual variable instance named `objects`.  Every translation unit that `#include`s your header file will get its own copy of that variable. So when you link multiple such units together into a single executable, you will get errors about all of the duplicate variables.

It looks like you want the variable to be instantiated only once in your `Structs.cpp` file and then shared by your other units.  So the variable needs to be declared as `extern` in your header file.  You should also move the `extern` declaration of the `gameObject` variable from out of your `CoreFuncs.cpp` file and place it in your header file, too.

Structs.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace Structs
{
    struct GameObject
    {
        std::string name;

        struct PosPoints
        {
            double px;
            double py;
        };

        std::vector<PosPoints> Points;

        double centroid[2];
        bool active;
        bool init;
    };

    extern std::vector<GameObject> objects;
    extern GameObject gameObject;
}

#endif
```

Structs.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Structs.h"

namespace Structs {
    std::vector<GameObject> objects;
    GameObject gameObject;
}
```

CoreFuncs.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CoreFuncs.h"
#include "Structs.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//render
void RenderShapes()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Structs::objects.size(); ++i)
    {
        Structs::GameObject &go = Structs::objects[i];

        for (size_t j = 0; j < go.Points.size()-1; ++j)
        {
            PosPoints &pt1 = go.Points[j];
            PosPoints &pt2 = go.Points[j + 1];

            glBegin(GL_LINES);

            glVertex3f(pt1.px, pt1.py, 0);
            glVertex3f(pt2.px, pt2.py, 0);

            glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1, 0);
            glVertex3f(0.9, 0.9, 0);

            glEnd();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have made both of those changes and i still get an unresolved external http://prntscr.com/p1gv70

Comment: @DylanRobertson "already defined" and "unresolved external" are two different kinds of errors. Your question's title does not match its body.

Comment: No, i meant after making the changes you sent i got that error. At the time of positing the error was http://prntscr.com/p1gzwd